# Can't figure out how to store input to dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I'm trying to assign a unique value to each new car.  How do I add the items via d[new_ID] = (new dictionary items) or the update() method?

```
# Create blank dictionary
d = {}

# The for loop executes until user has filled in each statement
for i in range(5):
    brand = str(input("Enter you car brand: "))
    model = str(input("Enter you car model: "))
    begodometer = str(input("Enter your starting odometer reading: "))
    endodometer = str(input("Enter your ending odometer reading: "))
    estmpg = str(input("Enter estimated miles per gallon: "))

# Not sure how to add ID key items to dictionary and then use update()

# Print dictionary
    print(d)
    break
```

Comment: In the for loop, you are asking the user the brand, model, etc. each 5 times. Not sure if this was the intent. To use the update method, just do d.update({key:val}). Could you show us what you want the dictionary to look like?

Comment: It's unclear what you want. Can you edit the question to show an example of the input and output if the program worked as desired?

Comment: I wanted the for loop to run until it's done asking each question.  The output I wanted as {'brand': 'ford', 'model': 'f150', 'begodometer': '838383', 'endodometer': '838383', 'estmpg': '83'}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
# Create blank dictionary
d = {}
# The for loop executes until user has filled in each statement                                                                                                                       
for i in range(5):
    brand = str(input("Enter you car brand: "))
    model = str(input("Enter you car model: "))
    begodometer = str(input("Enter your starting odometer reading: "))
    endodometer = str(input("Enter your ending odometer reading: "))
    estmpg = str(input("Enter estimated miles per gallon: "))
    #the "ID" is the iteration # but could be a random # if you like                                                                                                                  
    d[i]={"brand":brand,
          "model":model,
          "begodometer":begodometer,
          "endodometer":endodometer,
          "estmpg":estmpg}

# Print dictionary                                                                                                                                                                    
print(d)
```

Each 'record' is a new dictionary.

Cheers!

Comment: That seems to to work great!  The iteration # at the beginning looks a bit odd before the output, but the rest of the program is flawless.  Thank you!

Comment: Happy to help :)